# How do I not get a "failed" status in the "No One Escapes Cidhna Mine" quest if I sided with both factions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a question about the quest, "[No One Escapes Cidhna Mine](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:No_One_Escapes_Cidhna_Mine)". I've read articles in Skyrim wikia and [UESP](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:No_One_Escapes_Cidhna_Mine#Two_Rewards) that it is possible for one to side with both Madanach and Thonar to obtain both sets of Armor of the Old Gods and the Silver-Blood Family Ring.

To obtain both of the items you have to follow Madanach and kill him before the Dragonborn and Madanach walk out of the Markarth ruins and into Markarth city. I tried to do this but when I killed Madanach, the sub-quest "follow Madanach" turned to "failed" and instead I have to obtain Madanach's note and read it, although in the end I get both items. Now my question is: **Can I obtain both of the items from both side without having the status "failed to follow Madanach"?**

I wanted to have both of the items, you know, it's like a personal satisfaction, but if the cost to get them is to have a failed status then I would prefer tp pick one. To have a "failed" status is bugging my mind so and I tried my best not to. Any insight about this guys? Thanks.

Comment: Downvoters: Care to comment on why you downvoted this question? (So the OP will know what's wrong with the question and how to improve it)

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to avoid a failed objective in this case. You didn't follow him all the way and now he's dead, therefore you can't complete the quest objective to follow him all the way.

Quest objectives are frequently failed as a normal part of the game; all it means is that the objective can no longer be completed. The designers used this to create many either/or story branches, so failed objectives happen all the time – there are several quests where you *can't* avoid failing some objectives because they're mutually-exclusive decision branches.

You will have to make peace with having some failed objectives, since the alternative is quitting the game and walking away forever. They're just a game design tool, and don't leave a stain on your game. It's not a "status" on your savefile, it's only the game notifying you that the objective is no longer relevant to your playthrough. If you're a 100% completionist and want to beat Skyrim 100%, you will not be able to include "no failed objectives" in the definition of 100% since it's impossible.

Comment: I see. So there is absolutely no way to finish the quest objectives perfectly while obtaining both of the items. Thank you very much for the prompt answer. Really awesome!

Comment: @Pontius Yeah, there's no "perfect" in Skyrim, only "I feel I have made good choices." :)

Comment: @Pontius If you are playing on PC, modding makes everything possible.

Comment: @Batphobia Not really. There are things mods can't do (I've tried!), and there are also things modders won't even attempt (like redoing every quest so that there are no unfinishable branches).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still obtain both items even though you got the FAILED status. Make sure you killed Madanach before be escapes the dwarven ruin, take his note, kill the other forsworn around and talk to Thonar and he will give you the Silver-Blood Family Ring.